# Adding the id attribute to a Zend_Form_Decorator_Label

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I would like to add the id attribute to a label field in a Zend Form Element, but when setting 'id'=>'namelabel' in the decorator properties, it sets for='namelabel' in the label instead of adding the attribute of id='namelabel'

```
$name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('name');
$name->setLabel('Business Name:');
$name->addDecorator('Label',array('class'=>'form_label', 'id'=>'namelabel'));
$name->addDecorator('HtmlTag',array('tag'=>'span','class'=>'form_inputs'));
$name->setOrder(1);
$name->size='40';
```

renders

```
<label for="namelabel" class="form_label optional">Business Name:</label>
```

when I want it to render

```
<label id="namelabel" for="name" class="form_label optional">Business Name:</label>
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What ZF is doing is correct, because the `for` in your label should be the same as the `id` in your `input`. So you should not change this to be something different.

Have you tried:

```
$name->addDecorator('Label',array('class'=>'form_label', 'id'=>'name'));
```

More importantly, why do you need to do this?

**Edit after OP response**

The `for` should be unique enough for this, you can change your ZF code to the below, as you do not need to set an `id`

```
$name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('zf_element_name');
$name->setLabel('Business Name:');
$name->addDecorator('Label',array('class'=>'form_label'));
$name->addDecorator('HtmlTag',array('tag'=>'span','class'=>'form_inputs'));
$name->setOrder(1);
$name->size='40';
```

Then your javascript, if your using jQuery you can do this

```
$("label[for='zf_element_name']").html("Some new Label text");
```

Comment: I understand the for should be the same as the id of the input, which is why I still want the for attribute.  The reason I want a unique id attribute on my label tag is so that I can change the innerHTML on a javascript call

Comment: Thanks very much for your response.  Unfortunately I'm using prototype and not jQuery, is there a similar function in prototype I can use?

Comment: well I've found I can do a similar thing in prototype with 
var e = $$("label[for='name']");
var label = e[0];
label.innerHTML = "Some new Label text";